# How does a function works outside the main() block regarding the data types?

Tags: c, types

I am new to programming and want to understand how functions are handled in C. Given the following function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int calc(double m) {
    double result = (1 + sqrt(m)) / 2;
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    double n;
    printf("Enter value for n: ");
    scanf("%lf", &n);
    printf("Solution of n is: %lf\n", calc(n));    
    return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile, it gives me the error:

```
test.c:15:38: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
     printf("Solution of n is: %lf\n", calc(n));    
                               ~~~     ^~~~~~~
                               %d 1 warning generated.
```

Which I don't understand, because I thought I declared the correct type! Furthermore, the function itself (inside the `main` function) works perfectly with a result like `8.02` for `n = 5`. But if I use the function outside of `main(void)`, it gives me `8.00` as result for `n = 5` (for the case I am able to compile it). Something is wrong with the data types, please help!

Comment: You've declared `calc` as returning `int`.  Perhaps you want it to return a `double`?

Comment: `int calc(double m)` -> `double calc(double m)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that the type your function send back is an `integer` but you want to have a `double`. You also have to remove the extra `}`. The result of your function is hence cast as integer type, and printf needs `%d` to print integers.

See fixed code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double calc(double m) {
  
    double result=(1+sqrt(m))/2;
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    
    double n;
    printf("Enter value for n: ");
    scanf("%lf", &n);
    printf("Solution of n is: %lf\n",calc(n));    
    return 0;
    
}
```